# HTML5 and a dynamic local storage url?

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, document.write

Basically im trying to make a dynamic variable saved in local storage to be used as a redirect URL.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('webpage')</script>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function urlsave(){
localStorage.setItem('webpage','http://example.com/');
}
/<script>
```

So in theory it would send you to whatever URL is stored in the 'webpage' variable, this case being http://example.com/.

This is the idea anyway. Im still fairly new to programing, but am curius if this would work.
And if not, how would i MAKE it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set first the webpage, then call getItem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    localStorage.setItem('webpage','http://www.google.com');
    var dest = localStorage.getItem('webpage')
    document.write("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url="+dest+"'/>");
  </script>
```

Comment: Yeah, actually that makes a lot more sense.